# Is it possible to intercept Documentum API calls?

Tags: messaging, documentum, dfc

I have a need to handle different publication events in Documentum (DFC 6.5).  When content is published, I would like to fire a JMS message back to my application.

Is there any way to intercept the API calls so that I can handle my business logic?

Comment: what API calls do you want to intercept ?

Comment: Whenever something moves between lifecycle states (permission sets), I would like to send a JMS message to a topic or queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document has a lifecycle applied to it then add a custom java module on the "Post Change" tab of the lifecycle state

From Composer (6.7) help

> A post-change procedure executes after the state transition is complete. When the part of a transition that occurs within the transaction is complete, the system executes the post-change procedure. Failure of any part of the post-change procedure does not prevent the transition from succeeding

If not using lifecycles then, could do this in a document TBO or by attaching an Aspect